# Problems after py2exe compiling

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables, py2exe

I just compiled a script with py2exe, and I'm having some problems. In my script there are lines like this:

```
(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"\\"+os.path.basename(__file__))
```

and after compile, the **file** variable takes the name of the old python file. For example, myscript.py, even if I execute myscript.exe

Is there a workaround to solve this little issue? If you are asking, no, I can't write the name of final .exe file instead of **file**

Comment: FYI, better practice to use `os.path.sep` rather than hardcoding `"\\"`.

Comment: BTW, I'm getting other files from the same directory as my frozen executable with `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), 'win32service.pyd')`. But I switched from py2exe to pyinstaller.

Comment: thanks for advice, can you tell me why for curiosity?

Comment: Why what? Re: `os.path.sep`, portability -- my own code supports being run on Windows, but *also* on Mac or Linux; `os.path.sep` is always the correct separator for whatever OS you're running on. Even if you don't plan a non-Windows port presently, better to have fewer things you need to fix if you ever do one in the future.

Comment: ...re: pyinstaller, short form is that it's more actively maintained. I don't remember the specific issue that was the last straw on giving up py2exe.

Comment: Getting back to your immediate question -- what do you **want** the line in your code in question to evaluate to?

Comment: Can you provide your pyinstaller command for clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this will help you out if you are using py2exe:

```
file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
path = os.path.dirname(_file)
```

Comment: thanks! "os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])" solved my problem!